# Missing app.config file, and option on "Add New Item" does not show configuration file

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I'm missing my app.config file on Visual Studio 2017.

When I go added using the "Add New Item", the "Application Configuration File" is missing.  On the menu, Tools - Nuget Package Manage Manager, the "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" is missing.

Is there a way I can get those options back?  When I create a new project, the options are there, but for this particular solution is not.

Comment: Not a lot of info to go off of on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get those options back? When I create a new project, the options are there, but for this particular solution is not.

You should make sure that **there is a project in your particular solution**, if you have a solution without any project or all project are unloaded, you would not find the Application Configuration File and Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.

Besides, if there is a project in your solution, please check if all the projects are unloaded, if yes, you should Reload it:

[image]

If above answer does not solve your problem, please share more detail info, Some screenshots would be better.