# I can't see the App.config type under Add New Item option in VS 2017 Community

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I can't see the App.config type under Add new Item option. Please see the below screenshot. I am using VS 2017 Community version.

[image]

### Update

My question was a different than the marked duplicate.

I have found the answer myself. The answer is : In Visual Studio Installer, I have added ".Net Desktop development" under Workloads which was not added earlier. See the latest screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Note that we prefer succinct and descriptive titles here - remember questions are meant to help readers in the future. Please-help-me chat does not need to be added anywhere in a question, but especially not in a title.

Comment: Crowcoder , This is nowhere duplicated. my question was a different than what you have replied. Anyway I have found the answer myself. The answer is :

Comment: You need to ping via a handle e.g. @Crowcoder.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Project, click on settings, add an empty setting, there you have.

Answer (score 0):

You wont find an app.config unless you create a certain project type such as a web application or a class library (I believe). This is a auto generated file.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your application config with name: packages.config.

[appconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wyNL.jpg)

Comment: No, those are nuget package references.

Comment: OK, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807518/missing-app-config-file-and-option-on-add-new-item-does-not-show-configuratio